# How can I generate random words in PHP?

Tags: php

How I can get random words without repeating in PHP? Help

Comment: Could you maybe give us an example of what you're looking for?  What is a "random word"?  Is it a random collection of letters?  Or do you want dictionary words?  If the latter, you need to have a word list.  To avoid repeating, you should store the words you've already produced (probably using a *hashtable*) and avoid printing the same one twice.

Comment: Could you tell me 1 to 9 and a to z random words but with out repeating? Thanks.

Comment: @ABC: What do you mean by "without repeating"? `aabc` is not allowed, or `abc1`, `abc1` is not allowed?

Comment: _deleted_ (obviously it's too late for me *doze*)

Comment: Sorry for my unproficient English. I mean, I have to need min 1 to max 6 words with 0 to 9 and a to z but I don't need old words again. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate unique random alphanumeric characters that are 7 characters long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799495/generate-unique-random-alphanumeric-characters-that-are-7-characters-long)

Comment: No worries about your English, most of us are no native speakers ;-). karim79 already provided a nice solution.

Comment: *sigh* .. SO.. so many answers, and all fail to address "without repetition"

Comment: Words that exist in a dictionary or made up "words" (e.g strings of  characters a-zA-Z)? What are allowed characters? Should they all be the same length or should the length vary? Might make sense to enhance the question. If you elaborate, please update the question (so people do not have to read all the comments to understand what is requested). Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to type the alphabet manually, you can do the folowing:

```
<?php
function getRandomWord($len = 10) {
    $word = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));
    shuffle($word);
    return substr(implode($word), 0, $len);
}
```

[codepad example](http://codepad.org/9Y8CpnDx)

If this is a database id, i suggest you the folowing:

```
function createUniqueId() {
    while (1) {
       $word = getRandomWord();
       if (!idExists($word)) { // idExists returns true if the id is already used
           return $word;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this func

```
function randw($length=4){
        return substr(str_shuffle("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"),0,$length);
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Consider adding at least a tiny bit of explanation.

Answer (score 3):

```
$words = preg_split('//', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', -1);
shuffle($words);
foreach($words as $word) {
    echo $word . '<br />';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: @ABC Girl - That will shuffle the array of words, and print them out one by one, so no, no repeating.

Comment: If the array can have double values add `$words = array_unique($words);` before the `shuffle()`

Comment: Thanks, but I need random words with 0 to 9 and a to z keywords for my ID table. So, I don't need repeat.

Comment: @ABC Girl - something like that? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use `uniqid`.

```
echo uniqid(null, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a random word with SubString and String Shuffle funtions:

```
$password= substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-:,"),0,8);
```

This create a random word with 8 shuffle characters example (You can change the lenght at the function):

```
:s8wlip1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getrandomstring($length) {

       global $template;
       settype($template, "string");

       $template = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
       /* this line can include numbers or not */

       settype($length, "integer");
       settype($rndstring, "string");
       settype($a, "integer");
       settype($b, "integer");

       for ($a = 0; $a <= $length; $a++) {
               $b = rand(0, strlen($template) - 1);
               $rndstring .= $template[$b];
       }

       return $rndstring; 
}
```

Comment: Is without repeat? I mean, I have use this random keywords in database table ID. So, I don't need repeat keywords. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$letters  = array ( "a" ,"b" ,"c" ,"d" ,"e" ,"f" ,"g" ,"h" ,"i" ,"j" ,
                    "k" ,"l" ,"m" ,"n" ,"o" ,"p" ,"q" ,"r" ,"s" ,"t" ,
                    "u" ,"v" ,"w" ,"x" ,"y" ,"z" );

function letterfNum($letterNumber ,$resoltNumber){
    global $letters;
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < $resoltNumber ;$i++){
            $lettersTotal = "";
            $rand = array_rand($letters,$letterNumber);
            foreach($rand as $key => $letterIndex){ 
                foreach($letters as $orginalIndex => $orginalValue){
                    if ($letterIndex == $orginalIndex){
                        $lettersTotal .= $orginalValue;
                    }
                }    
            }
        echo $lettersTotal."<br>";  
        }
    }

    letterfNum(5,6);
?>
```

Comment: Isn't it too costly?