# Unique Alpha numeric generator

Tags: php, mysql, database, numbers

I want to give our users in the database a unique alpha-numeric id.  I am using the code below, will this always generate a unique id?  Below is the updated version of the code:

old php:

```
// Generate Guid 
function NewGuid() { 
    $s = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(),true))); 
    $guidText = 
        substr($s,0,8) . '-' . 
        substr($s,8,4) . '-' . 
        substr($s,12,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,16,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,20); 
    return $guidText;
}
// End Generate Guid 

$Guid = NewGuid();
echo $Guid;
echo "<br><br><br>";
```

New PHP:

```
// Generate Guid 
function NewGuid() { 
    $s = strtoupper(uniqid("something",true)); 
    $guidText = 
        substr($s,0,8) . '-' . 
        substr($s,8,4) . '-' . 
        substr($s,12,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,16,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,20); 
    return $guidText;
}
// End Generate Guid 

$Guid = NewGuid();
echo $Guid;
echo "<br><br><br>";
```

Will the second (new php) code guarantee 100% uniqueness.

Final code:

PHP

```
// Generate Guid 
function NewGuid() { 
    $s = strtoupper(uniqid(rand(),true)); 
    $guidText = 
        substr($s,0,8) . '-' . 
        substr($s,8,4) . '-' . 
        substr($s,12,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,16,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,20); 
    return $guidText;
}
// End Generate Guid 

$Guid = NewGuid();
echo $Guid;

$alphabet = '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';    

function base_encode($num, $alphabet) {
    $base_count = strlen($alphabet);
    $encoded = '';

    while ($num >= $base_count) {

        $div = $num/$base_count;
        $mod = ($num-($base_count*intval($div)));
        $encoded = $alphabet[$mod] . $encoded;
        $num = intval($div);
    }

    if ($num) $encoded = $alphabet[$num] . $encoded;
        return $encoded;
}


function base_decode($num, $alphabet) {
    $decoded = 0;
    $multi = 1;

    while (strlen($num) > 0) {
        $digit = $num[strlen($num)-1];
        $decoded += $multi * strpos($alphabet, $digit);
        $multi = $multi * strlen($alphabet);
        $num = substr($num, 0, -1);
    }

    return $decoded;
}

echo base_encode($Guid, $alphabet); 

}
```

So for more stronger uniqueness, i am using the $Guid as the key generator.  That should be ok right?

Comment: This is a regularly asked question: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799495/generate-unique-random-alphanumeric-characters-that-are-7-characters-long for a previous answer, although why do they need an alphanumeric ID rather than a simple sequential number?

Comment: "unique" and "random" aren't the same thing.

Comment: When you edit your question, you should leave the old info, then add the new stuff after under an edit heading. Otherwise it is confusing and answers stop making sense.

Comment: And if you just call uniqid("myserver",true) you will have a unique number. Doing the extra rand() in the prefix variable is unnecessary. Additionally using MD5 makes your unique ID more likely to have a collision because it is possible (very small possibility) that 2 messages have the same md5 hash. Bottom line is just use `uniqid` the way it was designed, to be a unique id generator.

Comment: @byron thanks.  will make sure i update correctly.  OK. So after removing the md5, this is how it should look, right:    // Generate Guid 
function NewGuid() {     
    $s = strtoupper(uniqid(rand(),true)); 
    $guidText = 
        substr($s,0,8) . '-' . 
        substr($s,8,4) . '-' . 
        substr($s,12,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,16,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,20); 
    return $guidText;
}
// End Generate Guid 

$Guid = NewGuid();
echo $Guid;
echo "<br><br><br>";

Comment: @Mark i am trying to give users a unique id

Comment: @AAA - but a unique ID can be a simple incrementing number rather than a random alphanumeric sequence

Comment: @mark is there an example i can use?

Comment: @AAA - the method most people use is a simple autoincrement column in their database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the id to be unique, you should [generate a GUID using uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

Your method will not guarantee uniqueness at all. And will likely create collisions.

Comment: I will make sure i update correctly.  OK. So after removing the md5, this is how it should look, right:    
function NewGuid() {     

    $s = strtoupper(uniqid(rand(),true)); 
    $guidText = 
        substr($s,0,8) . '-' . 
        substr($s,8,4) . '-' . 
        substr($s,12,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,16,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,20); 
    return $guidText;
}
// End Generate Guid 

$Guid = NewGuid();
echo $Guid;
echo "<br><br><br>";

Also, i am using this to give users an id for database purposes, so i have no way of checking.  For this purpose, this code is good right? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The code below will generate you a unique alpha-numeric ID from a number. I took it from [Flickr groups](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157616713786392/). Two functions to encode and decode:

```
$alphabet = '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';    

function base_encode($num, $alphabet) {
    $base_count = strlen($alphabet);
    $encoded = '';

    while ($num >= $base_count) {

        $div = $num/$base_count;
        $mod = ($num-($base_count*intval($div)));
        $encoded = $alphabet[$mod] . $encoded;
        $num = intval($div);
    }

    if ($num) $encoded = $alphabet[$num] . $encoded;
        return $encoded;
}

function base_decode($num, $alphabet) {
    $decoded = 0;
    $multi = 1;

    while (strlen($num) > 0) {
        $digit = $num[strlen($num)-1];
        $decoded += $multi * strpos($alphabet, $digit);
        $multi = $multi * strlen($alphabet);
        $num = substr($num, 0, -1);
    }

    return $decoded;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Usage:

```
echo base_encode(123456789, $alphabet); //should output: bUKpk
```

Comment: It's not a random generator thought.

Comment: @Buddy, thanks.  I am sort of having trouble generating a number, how do i echo? New to php so learning.  thanks again

Comment: It's unique ID for number 123456789, for another number it will return another ID. You can use a key id from field 'id' form your MySQL database.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, can you please see if the final code published in the question is ok for this purpose, i tweaked it a little bit using the $Guid from the top code and replacing that as a variable for 123456789

Comment: Hmm... I think you should use `uniqid` function, as Byron Whitlock offered. Just `echo uniqid();`. No need to make it difficult. The code I've povided is suitable for some different things.

Comment: OK thanks bud, using the GUID function then.  I will use the one you provided for things similar to its function (urls etc)  thanks again

Answer (score 2):

uniqid: `<?php $substr = substr(md5(rand()),0,22);echo " $substr ";?>`

Comment: Ralph:
 
 
uniqid: <?php
$substr = substr(md5(rand()),0,22);
echo " $substr ";
?>

Answer (score 1):

If it's truly random, then you can not guarantee uniqueness (unless you keep generating random keys and checking them against your database until you find a new one, which is a horrible idea).

**Does it really need to be random?**

Why not just use an autoincrement column in the table, and then convert it to base-62 (or so) if you want to reference it as an alphanumeric value?