# Why str_shuffle always generate similar patterns?

Tags: php, string, shuffle, secret-key

I am trying to generate 1500 authentication code using the following code:

```
    <?php
include "../include/top.php";

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");

$end=0;
while ($end<1500)
{
//generate an authentication code
$string="ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
$string= substr(str_shuffle($string),5,8) ;

//check whether generated code already exist
$query = "select count(*) from auth where code = '$string' ";
$stmt = prepare ($query);
execute($stmt);
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
check_bind_result($bind);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);

//If generated code does not already exist, insert it to Database table
if ($count == 0)
    {
    echo $string."<br>";
    $query = "insert into auth (Code) values ('$string')";
    $stmt = prepare ($query);
    execute($stmt);
    $end++;
    }
}
?>
```

It generated and inserted 1024 codes in database  and printed 667 codes in browser   within 15 seconds and the browser continue loading without inserting/printing further codes, until I close the browser window after half an hour. 
After that when opening any web page in browser from the WAMP, It shows like  the browser is loading and does not show the content. That is, I need to restart the WAMP after running this script before opening any web pages.
I have tried this many times.

Why the script does not generate 1500 codes and always stop when it reach the count 667/1024?

***UPDATE***

As an experiment, I have added an ELSE clause to the IF condition and wrote the code to print "Code Already Exist" in ELSE clause. And ran the script with an empty(truncated) copy of the same table , then it  print and inserted 1024 codes and after that, it print "Code Already Exist" continuously (Around 700 000+ entries within 5 minutes and continuing). And again when running the script with table having only 1024 rows, It doesn't print or insert even a single code. Instead it infinitely continuing print "Code Already Exist".
Another thing I observed that the very first 1024 iteration of the WHILE loop passes the IF condition(if the table is empty). And all the subsequent iteration failed the IF condition.

Comment: Any entries in the http servers error log file?

Comment: @arkascha NO errors found in Appache error log file

Comment: @arkascha I have updated my code. Actually I was posted the wrong code first time. Sorry..

Comment: It's hard to test without having the database structure and what your prepare/execute functions do (as they seem to be defined by you), but it sounds like you're leaking mysqli handles / connections. The difference between printed/stored could be caused by buffering in the httpd, and since it exhausts the available MySQL handles, the httpd has to be restarted to let them all go.

Comment: Do you have an index on the code column?  Otherwise you're doing an ever growing row by row search to find if the code already exists.  Also, I wouldnt use this for a password because its never going to reuse characters, so you are limiting the max number of permutations (unless thats specifically what you are trying to do).

Comment: @GrandmasterB Yes I there is an index(unique) in code column

Comment: Is this solved? If not check your `PHP error log` rather than your apache error log.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Already checked.  nothing found

Comment: @RiggsFolly Check the update in the question

Comment: @fiskfisk Check the update in the question

Comment: @arkascha Check the update in the question

Comment: @GrandmasterB Check the update in the question

Comment: One single comment mentioning all nick names would have been enough...

Answer (score 2):

I dont think that randomiser in str_shuffle is up to this.

If I run it once I get 1024 unique codes and then it just generates duplicates. If I then restart it, it will generate another 976 unique codes giving a total of 2000 codes on the database.

I therefore assume that the randomiser used by `str_shuffle()` needs a reset to accomplish the generation of the required 1500 unique codes.

Try this minor modification, it will at least stop the execution after 15000 failed attempts at generating a unique code.

Basically I think you have to come up with a much better randomisation mehanism.

```
<?php
include "../include/top.php";

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");

$end=0;
$dups=0;
while ($end<1500 && $dups < 15000)
{
    //generate an authentication code
    $string="ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
    $string= substr(str_shuffle($string),5,8) ;

    //check whether generated code already exist
    $query = "select count(*) from auth where code = '$string' ";
    $stmt = prepare ($query);
    execute($stmt);
    $bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
    check_bind_result($bind);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);

    //If generated code does not already exist, insert it to Database table
    if ($count == 0) {
        echo $string."<br>";
        $query = "insert into auth (Code) values ('$string')";
        $stmt = prepare ($query);
        execute($stmt);
        $end++;
    } else {
        $dups++
        echo "DUPLICATE for $string, Dup Count = $dups<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Why you need to restart = you set php timeout so it never times out.

Comment: Didn't see your edit before posting this. This may help you find a better algorithm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799495/generate-unique-random-alphanumeric-characters-that-are-7-characters-long

Comment: +1 Maybe just use a random starting position for `substr()`? Rather than use `5` each time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any specific coding errors.   The use of the str_shuffle for creating a authentication code is peculiar because it will prevent duplicated letters, making a much smaller possible range of values.  So it may just be repeating the patterns.

Try something like this instead, so that you are shuffling the shuffled string:

```
$origstring= str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789");

while ($end<1500 && $dups < 15000)
{
   $origstring = str_shuffle( $origstring);
   $string = substr( $newstring, 5, 8);
```

Or, use something like this to generate the string so that you can have duplicates, creating a much larger range of possible values:

```
   $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
   for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++)
   {
      $code .= $characters[mt_rand(0, 35)];
   }
```

Comment: The first shuffle execute one time only , and so it have no effect. Also I don't want to use a FOR loop for generating codes

Comment: @user2826057: But the 2nd shuffle is inside the loop and shuffles the shuffle. (Although maybe `$newstring` should be `$origstring` or something?)

Comment: @user2826057 why would you not want to use a FOR loop for generating codes?  What do you think shuffle() is doing under the hood?

Comment: @w3d yes, newstring should be origstring.  If the problem was that shuffle was only generating 1024 options from a given string, a second shuffle would widen that range.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fine-tune some variables in your `php.ini` configuration file, find those:

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 600
```

And, not mandatory, you can change those also:

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000   
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
```

After modification, restart your web server.

Comment: Actually if the script would be killed because of hitting some php limits, then the socket connection would be closed: the client would stop indicating loading activity and display either the result so far or a generic error, depending on the headers received so far. Instead the socket apparently is held open instead, so the OP writes.

Comment: @bodi0 I have tried your suggestions, but no result.  There is no such entries suhosin.post.max_vars  and  suhosin.request.max_vars in PHP.INI.     max_input_time is related with request data and there is no request data in the code, why it mentioned her?

Comment: The `suhosin**` variables are not present by default in `php.ini` configuration, indeed `max_input_time` is not related to your case.